# New DataFrame that is the average of each day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

```
    Site    Parameter   Date (LST)  Year    Month   Day Hour    Value   Unit    Duration    QC Name
1   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017    1   1   0   505 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
2   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 01:00:00 2017    1   1   1   485 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
3   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 02:00:00 2017    1   1   2   466 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
4   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 03:00:00 2017    1   1   3   435 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
5   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 04:00:00 2017    1   1   4   405 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
6   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 05:00:00 2017    1   1   5   402 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
7   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 06:00:00 2017    1   1   6   407 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
8   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 07:00:00 2017    1   1   7   435 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
9   Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 08:00:00 2017    1   1   8   472 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
10  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 09:00:00 2017    1   1   9   465 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
11  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 10:00:00 2017    1   1   10  473 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
12  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 11:00:00 2017    1   1   11  456 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
13  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 12:00:00 2017    1   1   12  474 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
14  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 13:00:00 2017    1   1   13  510 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
15  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 14:00:00 2017    1   1   14  596 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
16  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 15:00:00 2017    1   1   15  580 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
17  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 16:00:00 2017    1   1   16  556 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
18  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 17:00:00 2017    1   1   17  522 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
19  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 18:00:00 2017    1   1   18  495 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
20  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 19:00:00 2017    1   1   19  500 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
21  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 20:00:00 2017    1   1   20  484 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
22  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 21:00:00 2017    1   1   21  452 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
23  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 22:00:00 2017    1   1   22  427 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
24  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-01 23:00:00 2017    1   1   23  444 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
25  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-02 00:00:00 2017    1   2   0   428 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
26  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-02 01:00:00 2017    1   2   1   466 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
27  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-02 02:00:00 2017    1   2   2   452 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
28  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-02 03:00:00 2017    1   2   3   442 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
29  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-02 04:00:00 2017    1   2   4   390 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
30  Beijing PM2.5   2017-01-02 05:00:00 2017    1   2   5   317 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
```

How do I create a new DataFrame from the one shown here (truncated) that has all of the columns displayed but instead of having hour by hour values it shows the average value of the day?

Comment: Can you post a sample df, not picture

Comment: please refrain from using pictures, instead paste the text. that way we can read the data with `pandas.read_clipboad()`

Comment: Maybe you can try `df.groupby(df['Date(LST)'].dt.date).mean()`

Comment: @MattR see update

Comment: @Wen you can't ignore the fact that the full dataset likely has many different parameters recorded at multiple sites. Averaging e.g., PM2.5 with NOx is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
import datetime from datetime

df['Dates'] = df['Date (LST)'].dt.date

df['hour_average'] = df.groupby(['Dates'])['Hour'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: this returns DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic [split-apply-combine problem](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). However, being environmental data, there are some nuances here I can help you with.

Presumably, your full dataset has more than one parameter measured at more than one site, so you'll want to group by those. Since your dates are already parsed out into their components we might use those to get daily values.

As someone who works with environmental data like this on a daily basis, you also *always want to group by units* as well. While the units are consistent in this dataset, you'll eventually come across a dataset with consistent units. Getting into the habit of including units in the groups will help you spot those errors.

So let's read in your data:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

datafile = StringIO("""\
Site    Parameter   "Date (LST)"  Year    Month   Day Hour    Value   Unit    Duration    QC Name
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 00:00:00" 2017    1   1   0   505 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 01:00:00" 2017    1   1   1   485 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 02:00:00" 2017    1   1   2   466 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 03:00:00" 2017    1   1   3   435 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 04:00:00" 2017    1   1   4   405 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 05:00:00" 2017    1   1   5   402 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 06:00:00" 2017    1   1   6   407 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 07:00:00" 2017    1   1   7   435 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 08:00:00" 2017    1   1   8   472 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 09:00:00" 2017    1   1   9   465 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 10:00:00" 2017    1   1   10  473 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 11:00:00" 2017    1   1   11  456 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 12:00:00" 2017    1   1   12  474 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 13:00:00" 2017    1   1   13  510 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 14:00:00" 2017    1   1   14  596 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 15:00:00" 2017    1   1   15  580 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 16:00:00" 2017    1   1   16  556 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 17:00:00" 2017    1   1   17  522 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 18:00:00" 2017    1   1   18  495 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 19:00:00" 2017    1   1   19  500 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 20:00:00" 2017    1   1   20  484 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 21:00:00" 2017    1   1   21  452 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 22:00:00" 2017    1   1   22  427 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-01 23:00:00" 2017    1   1   23  444 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-02 00:00:00" 2017    1   2   0   428 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-02 01:00:00" 2017    1   2   1   466 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-02 02:00:00" 2017    1   2   2   452 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-02 03:00:00" 2017    1   2   3   442 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-02 04:00:00" 2017    1   2   4   390 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
Beijing PM2.5   "2017-01-02 05:00:00" 2017    1   2   5   317 µg/m_   1 Hr    Valid
""")

df = pandas.read_csv(datafile, sep='\s+', parse_dates=['Date (LST)'])
```

Then group by all of the columns that define a site-parameter-unit-day, select the "Value" column, and take the mean.

```
group_cols = ['Site', 'Parameter', 'Unit', 'Year', 'Month', 'Day']
df.groupby(by=group_cols)['Value'].mean()
```

And that gives:

```
Site     Parameter  Unit   Year  Month  Day
Beijing  PM2.5      µg/m_  2017  1      1      476.916667
                                        2      415.833333
```

Including the site, parameter, and units in the group by statement means that the simple statement above with scale up to a dataset with any number of sites and parameters.

Comment: ValueError: 'Date (LST)' is not in list is shown when trying to parse through the dates. When I convert the DataFrame into a string it does not put the timestamp in quotation marks like this: "2017-01-02 05:00:00"

Comment: that's just me mocking up your data. you should apply the concepts that I'm demonstrating to your actual data

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for [pandas.DataFrame.mean().](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

Example use:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["Beijing","PM2.5","2017-01-01","2017","1",df["Value"].mean(), 'ug/m_', '1 Day', 'Valid']

averages = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Site", "Parameter", "Date", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Value", "Unit", "Duration", "QC Name"])
```

Keep in mind that I hardcoded the values, based on how you get your information there may be better ways of importing the headers, and values. But this should show how to use df.mean()

Comment: that only works if there is only one day in the df. In my case I have to do the average value of all days.

Comment: Hard-coding all of these values is very antithetical to pandas and using code to analyze data.